# ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: The account for bucket "project name" has not enabled billing

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform

I am trying do deploy application to google cloud. I've just created account with free tier, registered but when I run

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/project-id/nest-angular-ssr
```

It says:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: The account for bucket "project name" has not enabled billing.
```

I've just started with this topic so any hint about enabling billing will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google recently changed it policy to require a valid billing account before you can use Cloud Build. The first 120 minutes per day are free. Read the details [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/pricing).

The solution is to create a Google billing account and assign the billing account to your project.

Go to the billing account page and create a billing account [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing).

Assign the billing account

1. Go to IAM & admin.
2. Select Manage resources.
3. To the left of each project is an ellipsis menu (three vertical dots). Click and select billing.